# Wanhao Duplicator 6 / Monoprice Maker Ultimate thread pitch or number of steps?

Tags: firmware, monoprice-maker-ultimate

Does anyone know the the thread pitch or number of steps for the Wanhao Duplicator 6 / Monoprice Maker Ultimate?

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to e.g. the Marlin printer firmware configuration file for the [Wanhao Duplicator 6](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/config/examples/Wanhao/Duplicator%206/Configuration.h) you will find that the steps per mm are defined as:

```
/**
 * Default Axis Steps Per Unit (steps/mm)
 * Override with M92
 *                                      X, Y, Z, E0 [, E1[, E2...]]
 */
#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT   { 80.0395, 80.0395, 400.48, 99.1 }
```

Sidenote, somebody who posted this has diligently tried to tune their machine, this should read:

```
#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT   { 80., 80., 400., 100. }
```

From these values you can tune your own if needed.

Now we do the math with the following assumptions:

- 400 steps per mm,
- standard 200 steps per revolution stepper motor (1.8°) and
- assuming that your board uses 1/16 µ-steps

Dividing the physical stepper steps per revolution by the firmware steps per millimeter we can calculate how much the nut advanced in a single revolution, i.e. 200/(400/16) = 200/25 = 8 millimeter. The nut therefor advanced 8 mm per complete revolution of the stepper. This means you will most probably have [Tr8x8(P2)](/q/5641) lead screws.

Do note that there are online calculators that can help you out doing the math for you, e.g. this [RepRap calculator page](https://blog.prusaprinters.org/calculator/).